# How do I open other programs via Lua without using the OS module?

Tags: lua

I need help knowing how to open programs without using the OS module, I am not using it because I'm making an FNF mod and the creator of Psych engine disabled the OS module entirely for security reasons.

Comment: Which other programs do you need to open?

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a way to open a program without the built-in OS library. But if you meant by opening .lua script, you can run it with `require()` function.

**Example:**

In others.lua

```lua
print('This is others.lua output')
```

In main.lua

```lua
print('This is main.lua output')

require('others') -- If you have the file hidden, you can just do './.others.lua'
```

The output

```
This is others.lua output
This is main.lua output
```

Answer (score 0):

If `os.execute` is not available you could try to use [`io.popen`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) instead; it is even more powerful than OS execute (allows executing a program and writing to it xor reading from it).

Alternatively, if the "external program" is a Lua-compatible shared library (`.dll` or `.so`), you can use `require` to "open" it.